# How can I parse dates with a suffix "th", "st" or "nd" on the day of the month?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm having trouble using `DateTime.Parse`

I'm handling a variety of formats of dates and some of which are of the format`January 11th` or `February 22nd` and so on.

`DateTime.Parse` throws an exception trying to parse these sort of dates.

I was wondering if there is a built in functionality in DateTime that I am missing, like a flag I can set that will make Parse behave in a more acceptable way.

I am aware that this is solvable with a relatively simple regular expression, moreover I already have a class that fuzzy matches dates that I wrote, however I would like to know if there is a built in way to perform this sort of extraction since it will more likely be easier to maintain in the long run than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: From where are you getting these dates (database, user input...)?

Comment: I think you will have to go with _Regex_.

Comment: @NDraskovic Around 100 sites across the internet

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There isn't anything inbuilt in .Net framework to parse dates in format of `January 11th or February 22nd` etc. You have to remove the suffix characters and then you can use  [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx).

For dates with Suffix `st`, `th`, you can use `string.Replace` to remove that part and then use `DateTime.TryParseExact`. Like.

```
string str = "1st February 2013";
DateTime dtObject;
string replacedStr =  str.Substring(0,4)
                         .Replace("nd","")
                         .Replace("th","")
                         .Replace("rd","")
                         .Replace("st","")
                         + str.Substring(4);


if (DateTime.TryParseExact(replacedStr, 
                            "dd MMMMM yyyy", 
                            CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture, 
                            DateTimeStyles.None, 
                            out dtObject))
{
 //valid date
}
```

For multiple formats, you can specify the formats in a string array and later you can use that.  It returns a `bool` value indicating if the parsing was successful or not.

Example from MSDN:

```
string[] formats= {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
                   "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                   "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
                   "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
                   "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"};
string[] dateStrings = {"5/1/2009 6:32 PM", "05/01/2009 6:32:05 PM", 
                        "5/1/2009 6:32:00", "05/01/2009 06:32", 
                        "05/01/2009 06:32:00 PM", "05/01/2009 06:32:00"}; 
DateTime dateValue;

foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
{
   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                              DateTimeStyles.None, 
                              out dateValue))
      Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
   else
      Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date.", dateString);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, Could you elaborate how this would solve my problem? (For example, January 22nd or February 11th or March 3rd? I was really hoping for a fuzzier solution (without having to explicitly specifying the formats)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, just added it to my answer, in that particular case, you have to remove suffix like `st`, `nd` etc from your string and then you case use TryParseExact

Comment: @Habib right, but if I remove these strings I can use DateTime.Parse and avoid TryParseExact altogether. I was hoping that there exists a more permissive version of Parse, January 11th 2010 seems like a pretty straightforward date to me

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I am pretty sure there is nothing built in for something like that.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Its not a format that is supported by the default `DateTime` feel free to design one that does.

Comment: @Ramhound Is there a way to pass a regular expression as a format or something similar?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - No...again not by default.

Comment: @Habib Thank you for your time and effort. This is helpful but it does not solve my issue, I'm sorry. If you edit your question to reflect the situation (that there is no built in way to parse these sort of dates) I will accept it.

Comment: @rpax, Somebody probably downvoted it and then later came back to remove the downvote

Comment: "22nd August 2013" wouldn't work as "st" in aug gets removed. And the last sub str assumes length of 4, but really needs to match length (5 in this case). I think you need to use a regular expression to do the string manipulation before passing it to DateTime.Parse as in @ma1169 's answer

Answer (score 14):

This is a very old question, however for anyone still looking into complex natural language date parsing I'd recommend using nChronic, a .NET port of the amazing (ruby based) chronic date parser.

The source for it is here:
[nChronic Github](https://github.com/robertwilczynski/nChronic)

It's also in Nuget as Chronic: [Chronic in Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chronic/)

Some very simple example code using this library would be like such:

```
using Chronic;
var parser = new Chronic.Parser ();
Span ParseObj;
DateTime ParsedDateTime;
ParseObj = parser.Parse ("January 11th");
ParsedDateTime = ParseObj.Start;
```

**Here are some examples of what it can handle:**

**Simple**

- thursday
- november
- summer
- friday
- 13:00
- mon 2:35
- 4pm
- 10 to 8
- 10 past 2
- half past 2
- 6 in the morning
- friday 1pm
- sat 7 in the evening
- yesterday
- today
- tomorrow
- last week
- next week
- this tuesday
- next month
- last winter
- this morning
- last night
- this second
- yesterday at 4:00
- last friday at 20:00
- last week tuesday
- tomorrow at 6:45pm
- afternoon
- yesterday
- thursday last week

**Complex**

- 3 years ago
- a year ago
- 5 months before now
- 7 hours ago
- 7 days from now
- 1 week hence
- in 3 hours
- 1 year ago tomorrow
- 3 months ago saturday at 5:00 pm
- 7 hours before tomorrow at noon
- 3rd wednesday in november
- 3rd month next year
- 3rd thursday this september
- 4th day last week
- fourteenth of june 2010 at eleven o'clock in the evening
- may seventh '97 at three in the morning

**Specific Dates**

- January 5
- 22nd of june
- 5th may 2017
- February twenty first
- dec 25
- may 27th
- October 2006
- oct 06
- jan 3 2010
- february 14, 2004
- february 14th, 2004
- 3 jan 2000
- 17 april 85
- 5/27/1979
- 27/5/1979
- 05/06
- 1979-05-27
- Friday
- 5
- 4:00
- 17:00
- 0800

**Specific Times (many of the above with an added time)**

- January 5 at 7pm
- 22nd of june at 8am
- 1979-05-27 05:00:00
- 03/01/2012 07:25:09.234567

etc

For invalid date ChronicNetCore.Parse returns null, not throwing exception, which may feels unusual compare with most .Net Parse methods (e.g. [DateTime.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-6.0) )

Comment: For .Net core Install-Package ChronicNetCore. https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChronicNetCore/

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem here's better way

```
  stringdate="August 19th 2000" 
  string pattern = @"\b(\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)\b";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0:MMMM,  d, yyyy}", rgx.Replace(stringdate, "$1"))  
  **result**    {19/08/2000 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
```

From [Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182290/regex-to-remove-ordinals) and [regex to remove ordinals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182290/regex-to-remove-ordinals) and [How can I visualize the way various DateTime formats will display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551655/how-can-i-visualize-the-way-various-datetime-formats-will-display)

**EDIT**

If the year is not specified:

```
    stringdate= rgx.Replace(stringdate, "$1");
    DateTime datetime;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(stringdate, "MMMM dd yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datetime))
    {
     // assuming no gap exist
     datetime = DateTime.Parse(stringdate += " "+DateTime.Now.Year);
    }
```

Now if the input string text is `"June 11th"`, it will be  `11/6/2021`.

There are More functions and ways to handle dates at [DateTime Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0).

If you dont want the year at all, then you can add the following line:

```
datetime.ToString("MM/dd");
```

Now the output will be "11/6"

Comment: This is nice, as it won't get a false positive on August, for instance.

Comment: What's the point of the String.Format part? The Regex will remove the ordinals, but the String.Format is expecting a date and being passed a string so it's never going to change anything unless I'm missing something?  Also "June 11th" is parsed into 2011-06-01 when I'd expect it to be <current year>-06-11

Comment: Hello @BrianHeward the parsing of  "June 11th 2011" is working as expected on my machine 11/06/2011!! Please double check your own code, as for String.Format(), it has nothing to do with regex, it has something to do with one of the overloaded parsing function, it's to show how to set your own format in case someone need to explicitly set parsing format when working with custom dates. so you can skip this option if you are working with standard format

Comment: The string I'm passing in isn't "June 11th 2011". I'm trying to parse "June 11th" the year isn't specified in the input, so I'd expect it to be parsed as current year. Instead the 11th (the day of the month part) is being parsed as the year, and the day is being presumed as 1.

Comment: I've gotten around this by always adding the year, if that fails, then parse it without adding the year (as "June 11th 2021 2021" won't parse.)

Comment: @BrianHeward I see, You are right, and your approach is correct. this library require a month, day and year, concatenating a year is simple using DateTime.Now.Year. "June 11th 2021 2021"  is undesirable situation , you should try to parse it then when it fails concatenate the year

Comment: The problem is "June 11th" does not fail. It parses to the incorrect value of 2011-06-01. So I have to concatenate the year on and attempt to parse that before trying without it. (As duplicate years do fail so I can test for and avoid  them.)

Comment: @BrianHeward as mention in my first comment there are multiple overloaded function to parse string, go to [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0) and get familiar with them. I will edit my answer and add a way to handle your case