# How can I parse a date string containing "17th" or similar suffixes?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime, datetime-format

I have a `string` that looks like *"17th December 2012"* and I want to convert it to a `datetime`, with a format of *dd/MM/yyyy*.

I have been on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050805/getting-day-suffix-when-using-datetime-tostring) link but that is the opposite of what I want to achieve.

I can do it by removing the suffix ("th" in "17th") by doing substrings and such and then converting it to `datetime`, but is there a *direct* way of achieving this?

a C# code would also do.

This is my code as of now, but it looks so ugly.. lol.

```
Private Function gettime(ByVal thetime As String) As DateTime        
    Dim result As DateTime
    Dim str1 As String = thetime
    Dim str2 As String = str1
    Dim ind As Integer = 0
    ind = str1.IndexOf(" ")
    str2 = str1.Substring(0, ind)
    str2 = Trim(StrReverse(str2))
    str2 = str2.Substring(2, 2)
    str2 = StrReverse(str2)
    ind = str1.IndexOf(" ")
    str1 = str2 & str1.Substring(ind)
    result = DateTime.Parse(str1)
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clever way to parse dates C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583285/clever-way-to-parse-dates-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the ability to add multiple format for your parse.

```
    Dim formats() As String = {"dd MMMM yyyy", "dd\s\t MMMM yyyy", "dd\t\h MMMM yyyy"}

    d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, formats, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Comment: Accepted this as an answer because of the code flexibility and simplicity.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

C#:

```cs
string datestring = "17th December 2012";
int indexOfFirstLetter = Regex.Match(
    datestring,
    "[a-z]",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Index;
datestring = datestring.Remove(indexOfFirstLetter, 2);
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(datestring);
```

VB.Net:

```
Dim datestring As String = "17th December 2012"
Dim indexOfFirstLetter As Integer = Regex.Match( _
    datestring, _
    "[a-z]", _
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Index
datestring = datestring.Remove(indexOfFirstLetter, 2)
Dim yourdate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(datestring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something?

Try this:

```
Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("17th December 2012")
```

**UPDATE**

If the problem is just the ordinal, you can create a simple procedure to remove them:

```
Sub RemoveOrdinals(time As String) As String
  time = time.Replace("nd", "")
  time = time.Replace("rd", "")
  time = time.Replace("st", "")
  time = time.Replace("th", "")
  Return time
End Sub
```

and simply call it before do the `DateTime` conversion.

Comment: thanks, but it returns an exception saying *'System.FormatException'*.  I have tried searching for datetime formats but I haven't seen one that fits on my problem..

Comment: The `RemoveOrdinals` method won't work as expected! Consider `August` which ends in `st`, you will end up with a date of `21 Augu 2012`.