# C# - Convert a string '07th December 2022' to DateTime

Tags: c#, date, format

We need to convert a string into a date. The data we received from client is in following format:

- 07th December 2022
- 08 December 2022
- 01st December 2022

Cab anybody suggest how this can be converted using any of C# date functions to a date format like YYYY-MM-DD.

Thanks

I tried few examples from here but none of them work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse dates with a suffix "th", "st" or "nd" on the day of the month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583285/how-can-i-parse-dates-with-a-suffix-th-st-or-nd-on-the-day-of-the-month)

Comment: So you have a string like `"07th December 2022 08 December 2022 01st December 2022"` that has three dates, in two different formats (with or without the `th`/`st`), with the month, day and year separated by spaces, and with the different dates separated by spaces. Do you have a general rule? My guess is that you'll need to preprocess things with a regex and then go from there.

Comment: Hmm... The last edit changed the nature of the question (changing `"07th December 2022 08 December 2022 01st December 2022"` to a bulleted list).  Was that the intent?

Comment: Either use Regex or string Split by Space and manipulate/clean the value to get day, month and year

Comment: So, did my answer help? By upvoting and/or accepting an answer (or answers - you can upvote more than one), you not only reward the answerer, you provide information to the next person who wants to know how to do this; in effect saying "this is a useful answer"

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?  I use a regex to split the day month and year up (ignoring "st", "nd", "rd" and "th" if they are there).  Then I reconstitute things into an easy to parse string and parse it.

I use named Regex groups to make getting the day/month/year out of the original string easier

It will, of course, half work (the regex half) and then fail if you pass it "99th Horse 1234":

```
public const string SampleString = "07th December 2022 08 December 2022 01st December 2022";
public const string Pattern = @"(?<day>\d{1,2})((st)|(nd)|(rd)|(th))? (?<month>[A-Za-z]+) (?<year>\d{4})";

public static Regex DateRegex = new Regex(Pattern);

public static IEnumerable<DateTime> ParseDates(string input)
{
    var matches = DateRegex.Matches(input);
    var result = new List<DateTime>();
    var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

    foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
    {
        var day = match.Groups["day"].ToString();
        var month = match.Groups["month"].ToString();
        var year = match.Groups["year"].ToString();
        var date = DateTime.ParseExact($"{day}-{month}-{year}", "d-MMMM-yyyy", culture);
        result.Add(date);
    }

    return result;
}
```