# DateTime TryParseExact a string containing a 3 letter month

Tags: c#, datetime

I am writing an extension method to parse a specific string which contains a date and a time into a `DateTime` object using the `DateTime.TryParseExact()` Method.

An example of the format is as follows: 
 `"29 November 2013 20:04"`

The code I am using to parse it to a DateTime is:

```
public static DateTime MyToDateTime(this string value)
    {
        DateTime converted;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out converted);
        return converted;
    }
```

The result is always `DateTime.Min` (i.e `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000`)

I cant figure out what is wrong with my format string. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I could be wrong, but don't you need 4 M's for a full month name? "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm"

Comment: I just realised I failed at writing my first question. The example format should be "29 Nov 2013 20:04". Although i did try and parse the full "29 November 2013 20:04" using dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm and it failed.

Comment: @Andrew If you fixed the month specifier, as you say, then the real problem is the hour specifier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from your comments:

1. if you want to parse 3 Letter Month use `MMM`.
2. if you want to parse 24-Hour format you should use `HH` instead of `hh`.

Try This:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out converted);
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the hour specifier all along.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems I see:

1. `November` is not a 3-letter month—that would be `Nov`. To parse a full date name, use `MMMM`.
2. To parse a 24-hour time use `HH`.

This should work:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out converted);
```

**Further Reading**

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an extra M and a capital H

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd MMMM yyyy H:mm", .....
```

See here for more info: [How can I visualize the way various DateTime formats will display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551655/how-can-i-visualize-the-way-various-datetime-formats-will-display)

Answer (score 1):

`MMM` stands for *the abbreviated name of the month*, so it's not what you're looking fore. Use `MMMM` instead.

Find all custom Date and Time format string on MSDN: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You should also check the value returned by `TryParseExact` method. It returns `false` when parse failed and `true` when it was performed without any problems.

And `hh` should be `HH` to parse hour part of your input.